# Passing Custom Class in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm passing a set of `MovieFile` objects from x.py to y.py and iterating through them, trying to use each object's attributes in y.py

**x.py**

```
mfSet = {}

def pop():
    ## populate mfSet with MovieFile objects
    m = MovieFile(title=t, year=y, dir=d, filename=f)
    mfSet.setdefault(str(m), []).append(m)

class MovieFile():
    def __init__(self, title, dir, filename, year=0):
        self.title = title
        self.year = year
        self.fulltitle = title if year == 0 else title + ' (' + year + ')'
        self.dir = dir
        self.filename = filename
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.title + ' (' + self.year + ') at ' + self.dir)
```

**y.py**

```
from x import MovieFile, mfSet, pop # not sure if I need to import MovieFile

pop()

for mf in mfSet:
    ft = mf.fulltitle # stacktrace says this attr doesn't exist for str object
    title = mf.title # printing shows that this is "<built-in method title of str object at 0x10d84a3f0>"
```

So my main questions are:

Why are the MovieFile objects compiling as str objects, and how can I use the `fulltitle` attr once I get use of those objects?

Comment: Hard to say why your `MovieFile` objects are "compiling" as str objects when you *replaced the code that creates your `MovieFile` objects with a one-line comment.*  :-)

Comment: its because he is iterating over the keys ... (since its a dict...) .. he probably would have figured it out with a simple `print mf`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: there's still an assumption there that that's how he's storing it... the `pop` code is the nub of the issue, though.

Comment: true... but a strong assumption based on the empirical evidence he did provide ...

Comment: I've filled in pop() with what I believe is the relevant portion of the code. Every field is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown what `pop` is (please include that code, it's the important bit). However, I expect what the problem is that `mfSet` is a `dict` and you are assigning `str` keys—perhaps `mfSet[str(mf)] = mf`. Iteration of a `dict` produces the keys, not the values of a dictionary.

You may want to use a `set` instead of a `dict`. Or, change `for mf in mfSet:` to `for mf in mfSet.itervalues():` (and change the variable name `mfSet` to not be misleading about type; [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) also recommends against camelCase in variable names).

---

So, you're grouping by `MovieFile.__str__()`. Very well, then. Here's how I might write that code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mf_collection = defaultdict(list)

def pop():
    ## populate the collection with MovieFile objects
    m = MovieFile(title=t, year=y, dir=d, filename=f)
    mf_collection[str(m)].append(m)

class MovieFile():

    def __init__(self, title, dir, filename, year=0):
        self.title = title
        self.year = year
        self.fulltitle = title if year == 0 else title + ' (' + year + ')'
        self.dir = dir
        self.filename = filename

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.title + ' (' + self.year + ') at ' + self.dir)
```

And y.py:

```
from x import mf_collection, pop

pop()

for mf_group in mf_collection.itervalues():  # this yields lists of MovieFiles
    for mf in mf_group:  # this yields the actual MovieFiles
        ft = mf.fulltitle
        title = mf.title
```

Because you're working with lists being the values, you've got another level of iteration to do.

Comment: Thank you, `mfSet.itervalues()` worked. I forgot that `{}` made a dict. I'll be switching over to a set(), but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`{}` makes a dictionary, not a set (this is because `dict` and `set` literals both use `{}` notation, but dictionary literals came first).

If you want an empty set, you need to use `set()`. Then `pop` becomes

```
mfSet = set()
def pop():
    mfSet.add(MovieFile(title=t, year=y, dir=d, filename=f))
```

Comment: Yeah, I kind of assumed you wanted a set since you never once mentioned making dictionaries :)

Comment: well I guess you know what I want more than I do haha